# Which command to restart postgresql 12 service

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-cluster

I am about to restart postgresql 12 service running on Ubuntu 18.
First, I check it's status : `sudo service postgresql status`. Its says :

```
postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor pres
   Active: inactive (dead)
lines 1-3/3 (END)...skipping...
postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Although it appears to be inactive, but I still can connect.

Then I run another checking : `systemctl status postgresql@12-main`. it says :

```
root@db-services:/# systemctl status postgresql@12-main
● postgresql@12-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 12-main
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/postgresql@12-main.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/postgresql@12-main.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-06-13 09:02:25 WIB; 5 months 27 days ago
 Main PID: 5807 (postgres)
    Tasks: 86 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-postgresql.slice/postgresql@12-main.service
           ├─ 1586 postgres: 12/main: postgres db_sync 10.100.3.248(61414) idle
           ├─ 1588 postgres: 12/main: postgres db_sync 10.100.3.248(61415) idle
           ├─ 1606 postgres: 12/main: docreg db_docreg 10.100.8.150(18385) idle
           ├─ 1607 postgres: 12/main: docreg db_docreg 10.100.8.150(18399) idle
           ├─ 1608 postgres: 12/main: docreg db_docreg 10.100.8.150(18401) idle
           ├─ 1609 postgres: 12/main: docreg db_docreg 10.100.8.150(18421) idle
           ├─ 2592 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.8.112(34956) idle
           ├─ 3518 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(48290) idle
           ├─ 5150 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.7.114(61504) idle
           ├─ 5807 /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres -D /data/postgresql/12/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.co
           ├─ 5883 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(48626) idle
           ├─ 6316 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(48704) idle
           ├─ 7049 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(48870) idle
           ├─ 7986 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.7.114(56240) idle
           ├─ 8146 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.8.114(47432) idle
           ├─ 8183 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(49022) idle
           ├─ 8360 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(49036) idle
           ├─ 8445 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.8.114(47478) idle
           ├─ 9590 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.8.106(56094) idle
           ├─ 9687 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.8.112(50980) idle
           ├─10148 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(40646) idle
           ├─10324 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(40680) idle
           ├─11079 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(49496) idle
           ├─11602 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(58152) idle
           ├─11886 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(44674) idle
           ├─12106 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 127.0.0.1(49618) idle
           ├─13112 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.6.145(55014) idle
           ├─13122 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.6.145(55015) idle
           ├─13145 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_mysapk 10.100.6.145(55016) idle
           ├─13202 postgres: 12/main: docudigtl db_docudigtl 10.100.7.114(62073) idle
           ├─13945 postgres: 12/main: checkpointer
           ├─13946 postgres: 12/main: background writer
           ├─13947 postgres: 12/main: walwriter
           ├─13948 postgres: 12/main: autovacuum launcher
           ├─13949 postgres: 12/main: stats collector
           ├─13950 postgres: 12/main: logical replication launcher
```

So it is actually active !

1. Whats the difference between the 2 commands?
2. Which one should I use for restart : `systemctl restart postgresql@12-main` OR `sudo service postgresql restart` ?

Answer (score 0):

There are special systemd services called [template services](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html).

A template service can take an argument like this: `template_service@argument`.

A template service is never started in itself, but it can be instantiated with a given argument. This means that the same (template) service may be running in multiple instances, each identified by its argument. For example:

> systemctl start template_service@a
> systemctl start template_service@b
> systemctl start template_service@c

In Debian and some derivative distributions (such as Ubuntu):

Every PostgreSQL instance (cluster) belongs to an instantiated `postgresql@` template service. The argument to the `postgresql@` service takes the form of `version-clustername`.

So for example `postgresql@12-main` is a systemd service which represents a PostgreSQL 12 server instance (cluster), with the cluster name `main` (which is the default).

There is another systemd service called simply `postgresql`. This is a kind of a catch-all service. If you start or stop it, all PostgreSQL instances will be started or stopped (this behavior can be disabled in [`start.conf`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/postgresql-common/pg_createcluster.1)).

You cannot, however, use `systemctl status postgresql` to check whether any PostgreSQL services are running, even if you only have a single PostgreSQL server set up in your system. You should always check the status of the particular instantiated service for a meaningful status report.

The [`service`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/service) command was used for the old init system (SysV init), before systemd came along. It still works for backward compatibility, but you really should use the `systemctl` command on systems where systemd is available.